# Reading and writing into the same file using a named pipe in C

Tags: c, linux, bash

More specifically, the program is supposed to emulate the bash command `cat file| grep $keyword > file`.
What I've done is: In the parent I read every character from the file and format them into lines which I then send to the named pipe, then in the child write the lines containing the keyword into the original file.

However, I receive a segmentation fault error when attempting to read the second character from the original file, which I assume is because the parent is waiting for the child to write in the original file instead of instead of reading the contents of said file.

Any help with the implementation/explanation of why exactly the error occurs would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

char key[20], *c,line[40];
int fd,fd_r,fd_w,fd_fr,fd_fw,counter=0;

int main(){

pid_t pid;
mkfifo("fifo1",0777);
fgets(key,10,stdin);

int k=0;

if ((pid=fork()) < 0)
        perror("err_fork");

if(pid){ //PARENT

        printf("%d\n",fd_r=open("prog.c",O_RDONLY));
        printf("%d\n",fd_fw=open("fifo1",O_WRONLY));
        while(read(fd_r,c,1)){
                line[k++]=(*c);
                while(read(fd_r,c,1) && ((*c)!='\n'))
                        line[k++]=(*c);
                line[k]=0;
                write(fd_fw,line,strlen(line)+1);
                memset(line,0,sizeof(line));
        }
        close(fd_r);
        close(fd_fw);
}
else{   //CHILD
        printf("%d\n",fd_w=open("prog.c",O_WRONLY));
        printf("%d\n",fd_fr=open("fifo1",O_RDONLY));
        while(read(fd_fr,line,sizeof(line))){
                c=strstr(line,key);
                if(c)
                        write(fd_w,line,strlen(line)+1);
        }
        close(fd_w);
        close(fd_fr);
}

unlink("fifo1");
}
```

Comment: You know that the bash command `cat file| grep $keyword > file` fundamentally won't work?  Typically it will just truncate the file.  I suppose you can emulate its brokenness if you really want, but what's the point?

Comment: Also, `while(read(...))` is not a good way to go about things, because in case of error, `read()` returns `-1`, which is nonzero and therefore will cause your loop to continue even though `c` does not contain new data.

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish between error and EOF, you can use `while (read(...) > 0)`

Comment: The child needs to truncate the file before it closes it. Otherwise, the file will still have lines at the end that weren't overwritten.

Comment: @NateEldredge This doesn't emulate that brokenness, because it doesn't use `O_TRUNC` when opening the output file.

Comment: Using a FIFO instead an anonymous pipe is simply making things harder, especially the cleanup in the face of interrupts etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're segfaulting because you're trying to read a byte into `c`.  However, `c` is an uninitialized global pointer and thus it's equal to `NULL`.  Trying to read data at that location is therefore an invalid use of memory.

What you do instead is declare

```
char c;
```

and then

```
read(fd_r,&c,1)
```

Comment: Well, it's global so it's initialized to NULL.  But indeed, you can't read into it.